# Change HTML with jquery click - and then back to original HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am looking to create my first web based jQuery app.  I have acheived half of the result that I want. Updating my button to change to 'Hide Answer' once clicked, however I would like the button to change back to the original text of 'Show Answer' when the user clicks an activates the toggle...

```
$(".answer-button").click(function(){
   $(this).html("Hide Answer").prev().toggle();
});
```

jsfiddle included here;

https://jsfiddle.net/rossmclenny/51jg4f79/1/

Comment: Why use a jsfiddle for this?  Just use stackoverflow's builtin feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can test the visible property

```
$(".answer-button").click(function(){
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    if($(this).parent().find('#answer').is(':visible')){
        $(this).html("Hide Answer");
    }else{
       $(this).html("Show Answer");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

just do that by testing the text value:

```
    $(".answer-button").click(function () {
      if ($(this).text().includes("Show")) {
        $(this).html("Hide Answer").prev().toggle();
      } else {
        $(this).html("Show Answer").prev().toggle();
      }
    });
```